# LDAP: Dynamic Groups, memberurl evaluation

Tags: dynamic, ldap, directoryservices

I been using apache directory studio for accessing the remotely installed ldap server and i am kind of stuck at this dynamic groups, where in we provide a ldap search url for memberURL attribute. The apacheDS doesn't seem to evaluate the attribute and show the users under that group, or I may be expecting it to evaluate it. Is there a way or any other tool by which I can check the ldap search url that I have framed is rightly done ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider mastering `ldapsearch`. This tool should be available on UNIX boxes these days. ADS is a great tool, but sometimes it gets in the way (constant entry reloads, etc).

For example:

```
ldapsearch -h hostname -p port \
    -D bindDN -w bindPassword \
    -b <dn-of-group> -s base \
    '(&)' memberURL
```

If the difficulty is with Apache DS ... that's another story.

#### see also

- [Mastering ldapsearch](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldapsearch.html)